# Trouble implementing Ax = b solver using LU decomposition

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, linear-algebra

Im trying to solve linear systems of the form Ax = b where A is an nxn matrix of real numbers and b a 1xn vector of real numbers, using the A = LU algorithm.

I've implemented the necessary functions, but Im not sure in which function or functions the problem lies.

```
import numpy as np

 def forward_sub(L, b):
    """Given a lower triangular matrix L and right-side vector b,
    compute the solution vector y solving Ly = b."""

    y = []
    for i in range(len(b)):
        y.append(b[i])
        for j in range(i):
            y[i]=y[i]-(L[i, j]*y[j])
        y[i] = y[i]/L[i, i]

    return y

def backward_sub(U, y):
    """Given a lower triangular matrix U and right-side vector y,
    compute the solution vector x solving Ux = y."""



    x = [0 for i in range(len(U))]

    for i in range(len(U)-1, 0, -1):
        x[i] = U[i, i]/y[i]
        for j in range (i-1, 0, -1):
            U[i, i] += U[j, i]*x[i]

    return x


def lu_factor(A):


    #LU decompostion using Doolittles method

 L = np.zeros_like(A)
 U = np.zeros_like(A)

 N = np.size(A,0)

 for k in range(N):
        L[k, k] = 1
        U[k, k] = (A[k, k] - np.dot(L[k, :k], U[:k, k])) / L[k, k]
        for j in range(k+1, N):
            U[k, j] = (A[k, j] - np.dot(L[k, :k], U[:k, j])) / L[k, k]
        for i in range(k+1, N):
            L[i, k] = (A[i, k] - np.dot(L[i, :k], U[:k, k])) / U[k, k]


  return (L, U)

def lu_solve(L, U, b):
    # Step 1: Solve Uy = b using forward substitution

    # Step 2: Solve Lx = y using backward substitution

    y = forward_sub(L,b)
    x = backward_sub(U,y)

    return x


def linear_solve(A, b):
    # ...

    L, U = lu_factor(A)
    x = lu_solve(L,U,b)
    return x


b = [6,-4,27]
A = np.matrix([[1,1,1],[0,2,5],[2,5,-1]])

print(linear_solve(A,b))
```

Choosing A and b as above gives x = [0,-0.5,-0.42] as my solution vector, however it should give x = [5,3,-2]

Comment: My suggestion would be to take an example you can work out by hand and walk through the steps with a debugger by setting breakpoints at each step. Then you can find the offending piece of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`A` is an integer matrix. That makes the `L` and `U` integer matrices as well, but the right results are:

```
L:
[[1.  0.  0. ]
 [0.  1.  0. ]
 [2.  1.5 1. ]]
U:
[[  1.    1.    1. ]
 [  0.    2.    5. ]
 [  0.    0.  -10.5]]
```

Some fractional values are required. In general that is the case for LU decomposition even if the input consists of integers. There is some division going on after all.

Changing the data type fixes that. For example:

```
A = np.matrix([[1.,1,1],
               [0,2,5],
               [2,5,-1]])
```

`backward_sub` is broken, I'm not sure how exactly but in any case it's a strange implementation. This one seems to work:

```
def backward_sub(U, y):
    """Given a lower triangular matrix U and right-side vector y,
    compute the solution vector x solving Ux = y."""

    x = np.zeros_like(y)

    for i in range(len(x), 0, -1):
      x[i-1] = (y[i-1] - np.dot(U[i-1, i:], x[i:])) / U[i-1, i-1]

    return x
```

Result is `[ 5.  3. -2.]`, try it one [ideone](https://ideone.com/2mhhf7)